# Sharepoint issue, selective behavior?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I was recently assigned a task in Sharepoint as part of my internship, and it's been puzzling me for some days. Note that this is the first time I'm using Sharepoint so I might be using wrong terms here.

They have a site that contains 2 web parts; a list called "Company Directory" and below it, a list (I think) called My Information. The way this is supposed to behave is that all users in the group "Employee Audience" can view both web parts.

Employees are supposed to "add a new item" to the Company Directory list where they will enter their personal information. After adding it, the bottom web part "My Information" should show the information they entered and an option to edit. So far, they got all of this working already.

However, there's an issue with certain employees where they can't see the information they have entered. I have tested different things with 2 employees, which belong to the Employee Audience group and can see both lists, but only one of them can see the information he entered and edit it.

I don't understand why it would work for one of them but not the other, I have tried making them add the information on the same date as well as on different dates, making them add the information from the same computer, but the same thing happened.

I'm at a loss now. Remember, I'm a newbie with this application so I'm probably missing something obvious, so whatever you can think of will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this most likely has to do with individual permissions of the company directory list. Check the permission groups for each of hese indivuals and compare them to the company directory list for any discrepencies.

Comment: Thing is, both employees can ADD information to the list, it just doesn't show it as editable for one of them. But I will double check just in case.

Comment: there are possible security configurations for various operations when it comes to a list. such as add/edit/delete so its certainly possible.

Comment: It gets weirder... I added some information to the list and I can't view it on the My Information and consequently can't edit it. NOTE: I'm a user with Full Control over the Company Directory list (I couldn't find where to set individual permissions such as add,remove,edit)

Comment: Actually I think I found it, went to the list's permissions and the group has "Contribute - Can view, add, update, and delete." permissions. If an employee is found in 2 groups, could the permissions override or something like that?

Comment: Yes, the higher permission will override the lower. Ex: if a user has Full Control AND Contribute, the user will actually have Full Control.

Comment: I had hoped it was the other way around.. still clueless then.